# comparing two text files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two text files `bala.txt` and `bala1.txt`

bala.txt contains text line by line as

```
balamurugan,rajendran,chendurpandian
christopher
updateba
```

bala1.txt contains text line by line as

```
ba
```

Here i need to check bala1.txt with bala.txt and write into a log file as

```
LineNo : 0 : balamurugan,rajendran,chendurpandian
LineNo : 2 : updateba
```

now its writing only one line as

```
LineNo : 0 : balamurugan,rajendran,chendurpandian
```

after that while loop is getting out

Here is my code

```
while (((line = file.ReadLine()) != null & (line2 = file2.ReadLine()) != null))
                        {
                            if (line.Contains(line2))
                            {
                                dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + line + "<br />");
                            }
                            counter++;
                        }
```

any suggestion??

EDIT:

```
string FilePath = txtBoxInput.Text;
    string Filepath2 = TextBox1.Text;
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    string line2;


        DirectoryInfo Folder = new DirectoryInfo(textboxPath.Text);
        var dir = @"D:\New folder\log";

        if (Folder.Exists)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }
        if (File.Exists(FilePath) & File.Exists(Filepath2))
        {
            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            using (var file = File.OpenText(FilePath))
            using (var file2 = File.OpenText(Filepath2))
            using (var dest = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(dir, "log.txt")))
            {
                while (((line = file.ReadLine()) != null & (line2 = file2.ReadLine()) != null))
                {
                    if (line.Contains(line2))
                    {
                        dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + line + "<br />");
                    }

                    counter++;
                }

            }
```

}

EDIT(2):
  I need to create two text files into the folder log and write into that text files as `ba.txt` with contents as

```
LineNo : 0 : balamurugan,rajendran,chendurpandian
LineNo : 2 : updateba
```

and `ra.txt` with contents as

```
LineNo : 0 : balamurugan,rajendran,chendurpandian
```

Any Suggestion??

EDIT(3):
 I need to create a folder named `Log` through code and in that log folder `ba.txt` and `ra.txt` have to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
string FilePath = txtBoxInput.Text, Filepath2 = TextBox1.Text;
int counter = 0;
string line, line2;

DirectoryInfo Folder = new DirectoryInfo(textboxPath.Text);
var dir = @"D:\New folder\log";

if (Folder.Exists)
    if (!Directory.Exists(dir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

if (File.Exists(FilePath) && File.Exists(Filepath2))
{   // Read the file and display it line by line.
    using (var file = File.OpenText(FilePath))
    {
        using (var file2 = File.OpenText(Filepath2))
        {
            while((line2 = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //YOU NEED TO CHECK IF FILE ALREADY EXISTS
                // AND YOU WANT TO OVERWRITE OR CREATE NEW
                //WITH SOME OTHER NAME
                //---------------------------------------CREATE NEW FILE FOR
                //---------------------------------------EACH LINE IN file2
                using (var dest = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(dir, line2 + ".txt")))
                {
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.Contains(line2))
                            dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + 
                                counter.ToString() + " : " + line + "<br />");
                        counter++;
                    }
                    //IF THE SECOND FILE ONLY CONTAINS 1 LINE THEN YOU
                    //DON'T NEED THIS.
                    //we need to go to begning of first file
                    file.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: to get file path from user.

Give a button to open file dialog box to chose file or folder browser dialog if you want to get directory name to save log files.

```
//OPEN FILE -- you will need two buttons one 
//for each text boxes
void btnFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fbd = new OpenFileDialog();
    fbd.Multiselect = false;
    fbd.CheckFileExists = true;
    fbd.CheckPathExists = true;
    if(fbd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.Ok)
    {
        textBox1.Text = fbd.FileName;
    }
}

//SELECT FOLDER
string _logFolderPath;//use this inplace of @"D:\new folder\log";
void btnFolder_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if(fd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        _logFolderPath = fd.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: @The VillageIdiot suppose if i have two text in my bala1.txt as ba and ra..and i want to write in to a seperate text file as ba.txt and ra.txt for the matched contents....Is that possible???

Comment: @The VillageIdiot see my EDIT(2)

Comment: @The VillageIdiot that worked..without giving the hardcode path in the code whether is it possible to create a folder by giving it in the textbox itself like this D:\Log

Comment: @bala3569 it is possible. you can use `OpenFileDialog` dialog to get complete path of file, put it into textbox and use in code to open file. I have updated code.

Comment: yes @bala3569 I went back to format it nicely :D I'm sort of obssessed with well formatted code.

Comment: @The VillageIdiot instead of dir what i have to use

Comment: @bala3569 you can use `_logFolderPath` variable that contains path of the directory selected by user, but do check if it is empty or contains valid directory path.

Comment: @The VillageIdiot is it possible to use openfiledialog in web application

Comment: :) nope you cannot do it in web.

Comment: @The VillageIdiot now trying in winforms ll ask u wen help needed

Comment: @The VillageIdiot Instead of giving path in textbox i need to browse and select the path...how to do in winforms

Comment: add a textbox named text1 adda button next to it and name it btn1 now on `btn1_click` event write code written in ` btnFile_Click` method and change `textBox1.Text = fbd.FileName;` to `text1.Text = fbd.FileName;`

Comment: @The VillageIdiot Did it..But all these text files ba.txt and ra.txt are created in the selected folder..What i need is inside the selected folder, a folder named log has to be created and inside that log folder these text files ba.txt and ra.txt has to be created...got it???

Answer (score 1):

The underlying stream for the second file reader is reaching the end of the stream and not being reset before the next iteration of the loop.  You'll need to copy all the lines of each file into memory before comparing them.  Try this:

```
List<string> file1Lines = new List<string>();
List<string> file2Lines = new List<string>();

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    file1Lines.Add(line);
}

while ((line2 = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    file2Lines.Add(line2);
}

foreach (string f1line in file1Lines)
{
    foreach (string f2line in file2Lines)
    {
        if (f1line.Contains(f2line))
        {
            dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + f1line + "<br />");
        }

    }
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: @Kyle Trauberman line2 is reading next line and returns null so the while loop exits

Comment: @Kyle Trauberman Ya that worked...suppose if have two text in my bala1.txt as ba and ra..and i want to write in to a seperate text file as ba.txt and ra.txt for the matched text....Is that possible???

Comment: Sure, just create a new StreamWriter for each file, and write those inside the second nested foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Comparer(string fileLocation1, string fileLocation2, string resultLocation)
{
    StreamReader source = new StreamReader(fileLocation1);
    StreamReader pattern = new StreamReader(fileLocation2);
    StreamWriter result = File.CreateText(resultLocation);

    //reading patterns
    List<String> T = new List<string>();
    string line;
    while ((line = pattern.ReadLine()) != null)
        T.Add(line);
    pattern.Close();

    //finding matches and write them in output
    int counter = 0;
    while ((line = source.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foreach (string pat in T)
        {
            if (line.Contains(pat))
            {
                result.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + line);
                break; //just if you want distinct output
            }
        }
        counter++;
    }

    source.Close();
    result.Close();
}
```

----------------------------EDIT----------------------------------
for the one you mentioned in comment

```
private void Comparer(string fileLocation1, string fileLocation2, string resultFolder)
{
    StreamReader source = new StreamReader(fileLocation1);
    StreamReader pattern = new StreamReader(fileLocation2);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(resultFolder);
    //reading patterns
    List<String> T = new List<string>();
    string line;
    while ((line = pattern.ReadLine()) != null)
        T.Add(line);
    pattern.Close();

    //finding matches and write them in output
    int counter;
    foreach (string pat in T)
    {
        StreamWriter result = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(resultFolder, pat + ".txt"));
        source.BaseStream.Position = counter = 0;
        while ((line = source.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(pat))
                result.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + line);
            counter++;
        }
        result.Close();
    }
    source.Close();
}
```

Comment: @HPT suppose if i have two text in my bala1.txt as ba and ra..and i want to write in to a seperate text file as ba.txt and ra.txt for the matched text....Is that possible???

Comment: @HPT I need to create a folder named log through code and in that log folder ba.txt and ra.txt have to be created

Comment: @HPT  DirectoryInfo Folder = new DirectoryInfo(textboxPath.Text);
        var dir = @"D:\New folder\log";

        if (Folder.Exists)
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
        }