# creating a folder without giving hardcore path in the code

Tags: c#

i need to create a folder named log after giving the path in a textbox like `D:\New Folder` without giving the hardcore path in the code like `var _logFolderPath = @"D:\New Folder\log";`
and after that i need to create two text files ba.txt and ra.txt in that log folder

This is my code

```
 DirectoryInfo Folder = new DirectoryInfo(textboxPath.Text);
 var _logFolderPath =textboxPath.Text;
 if (Folder.Exists)
 if (!Directory.Exists(_logFolderPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(_logFolderPath);
```

and

```
  using (var dest = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(_logFolderPath, line2 + ".txt")))
```

for reference
[comparing two text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253090/comparing-two-text-files)

Comment: Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: I'm with @DavidHeffernan - Can you explain what the issue is?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253090/comparing-two-text-files EDIT(3)

Comment: after giving the path in the textbox as D:\New Folder...i need a folder named log have to be created inside that New Folder

Comment: @bala - that's just restating the above. You already have the File and Directory methods at hand, what is your problem with them?

Comment: And you've written some code, which you have provided, but you haven't explained how that code fails

Comment: i dint know how to combine those two as Henk Holterman said

Comment: var _logFolderPath = Path.Combine(textboxPath.Text.Trim(), "log");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about changing the 2nd line to:

```
var _logFolderPath = Path.Combine(textboxPath.Text.Trim(), "log");
```